# How to avoid python from rounding off the numbers?

Tags: python-2.7, powershell-2.0

I'm really new to python & overall. So i was writing this code as a part of some practice which involves making a converter that can convert input values of weight and height from kg to lbs and inches to feet respectively when the code is run via PowerShell.

With the first piece of code the output gets rounded off and i'd like to know why? Also, how can this be avoided.

However, with the second piece of code, the output isn't rounded off. Why?

```
    print "This is my personal converter."
height = int(raw_input("what is your height in inches? "))
weight = int(raw_input("what is your wieght in kilograms? "))
kg_to_lbs_rate = 2.20462
inches_to_feet_rate = 0.0833333

print "Since your height in inches is equal to %d, then your height in feet should equal to %d" % (height, height * inches_to_feet_rate),"feet"
print "Since your weight in kilograms is equal to  %d, then your weight in lbs should equal to %d" % (weight, weight * kg_to_lbs_rate),"lbs"
```

---

```
    print "This is my personal converter."
height = int(raw_input("what is your height in inches? "))
weight = int(raw_input("what is your wieght in kilograms? "))
kg_to_lbs_rate = 2.20462
inches_to_feet_rate = 0.0833333

print "Since your height in inches is equal to %d, then your height in feet should equal to " % height, height * inches_to_feet_rate,"feet"
print "Since your weight in kilograms is equal to  %d, then your weight in lbs should equal to" % weight, weight * kg_to_lbs_rate,"lbs"
```

[Here's the output of both the codes when run in PowerShell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Y115.jpg)

Comment: It's not clear where it is rounded off but you are using `%d` for display. It is for integers.

Comment: If you are new to Python, why are you starting with Python 2? The [Stack Overflow Python community](http://sopython.com) overwhelmingly [recommends](http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F) starting with Python 3, as does [python.org itself](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3). Version 3 is the present and future of the language, while 2 is the past. In learning 2 first, you'll pick up many bad habits that will need to be corrected when you learn 3 (which you'll need to do eventually), so it's much better to start with 3 first, then learn the differences in 2 later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ayhan is right, it is rounded off when you display it since you use `%d`. See the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting). If you want to display a float you can use `%f`:

```
print 'test: %f', 3.43
```

However it's usually preferred to use str.format

```
print 'test: {}'.format(3.43)
```

Comment: I get it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the first code u specified %d to pull only integer part from the result.
In the second code there is no specific datatype,so it prints exact answer.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks